# How to set popup on page load first time only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set a popup window that open when first time the page load? i m using this code for my popup how to set session for this popup? is there any way to use ip as session?

```
    <script>
        !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("a#example1").fancybox();

        $("a#example1").trigger('click');


    });
    </script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />


</head>



<body>

<a id="example1" href="images/pic.jpg"></a> 



</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for a cookie, and if not there, do the popup and set the cookie for next time; if the cookie is there, don't do the popup. Quirksmode has [some functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for making cookies easier, or of course there's the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) (and probably about 50 others).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Demo :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       if($.cookie('popup') != 1){
           $.cookie('popup', '1');
           $("a#example1").fancybox();
           $("a#example1").trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

Comment: @capri did you download the plugin and load it inside your document, if so provide the script you did

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions for this would be an unnecessary load on your server. Use cookies instead, that helps to store data in the user's computer.

Use Javascript/your server language to check the cookie and show the popup based on its value!

Answer (score 0):

You can you Cookies or localStorage
Using Cookies:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var loadfirst = getCookie("loadfirsttime");
if(loadfirst == null){
setCookie("loadfirst", "again" 1); // 1 is the number of days
$("a#example1").fancybox();
 $("a#example1").trigger('click');
}
});
```

Using LocalStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var loadfirst = localStorage.getItem("loadfirsttime");
if(loadfirst == null){
localStorage.setItem('loadfirst ', 1); // 1 is value assigned.
$("a#example1").fancybox();
 $("a#example1").trigger('click');
}
});
```

Thanks